# I can't get `golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert` to work (for gRPC), I get an `acme_account+key` file and no X509 cert

Tags: go, lets-encrypt, autocert

> **UPDATE** After much debugging, I uncovered `Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` and suspect (!?) this results from the recent expiration of Let's Encrypt's root cert.

I accept that "This package is a work in progress and makes no API stability promises." but, *if* it no longer works (and it's much more likely that my code|deployment is at issue), then perhaps the repo can be marked e.g. [Here be dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons).

The code results in an `acme_account+key` (`EC PRIVATE KEY`) but no certs I'm challenged to get `autocert` to disclose (log) its magic in order to understand where I'm going wrong.

The code is essentially the repo's [`Manager`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert#example-Manager) example with input from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49966863/609290). I *assume* that `GetCertificate` blocks on the completion of the ACME flow.

Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/health"
    healthpb "google.golang.org/grpc/health/grpc_health_v1"
)

const (
    email string = "my@email.com"

var (
    host = flag.String("host", "foo.example.org", "Fully-qualified domain name")
    port = flag.Uint("port", 443, "gRPC service port")
    path = flag.String("path", "", "Folder location for certificate")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *host == "" {
        log.Fatal("Flag --host is required")
    }
    log.Printf("Host: %s", *host)
    log.Printf("Port: %d", *port)

    if *path == "" {
        log.Fatal("Flag --path is required")
    }
    log.Printf("Path: %s", *path)

    addr := fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port)

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %s", err)
    }

    m := &autocert.Manager{
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache(*path),
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(*host),
        Email:      email,
    }

    go func() {
        log.Println("Starting HTTP server w/ autocert handler")
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":http", m.HTTPHandler(nil)); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("HTTP failure\n%s", err)
        }
    }()

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        GetCertificate: func(hello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
            cert, err := m.GetCertificate(hello)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("GetCertificate\n%s", err)
            }
            return cert, err
        },
    }

    opts := grpc.Creds(credentials.NewTLS(tlsConfig))
    server := grpc.NewServer(opts)

    healthcheck := health.NewServer()
    healthpb.RegisterHealthServer(server, healthcheck)

    log.Println("Starting gRPC server")
    if err := server.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("gRPC failure\n%s", err)
    }
}
```

I'm deploying to a (Google Compute Engine) Container VM, the equivalent docker command is:

```sh
docker run \
--name=autocert \
--detach \
--net=host \
--volume=/tmp/certs:/certs \
${IMAGE} \
--host=${HOST} \
--port=${PORT} \
--path=/certs
```

And container logs:

```
2021/11/25 17:30:00 Host: [HOST]
2021/11/25 17:30:00 Port: 443
2021/11/25 17:30:00 Path: /certs
2021/11/25 17:30:00 Starting gRPC server
2021/11/25 17:30:00 Starting HTTP server
```

The host's `/tmp/certs` directory receives `acme_account+key` (which I've struggled to find explained by Google) but suspect (!?) is the initial phase of [Domain Validation](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/#domain-validation). It contains a private key (`BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY`).

Even after some time with the server running, no further files are persisted.

I receive no emails from Let's Encrypt at the configured email address.

Unfortunately, while easy to use, [`autocert`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert) produces little logging and I've been unable to determine whether I can log the ACME flow that's (hopefully) taking place.

Since adding the anonymous function for `GetCertificate`, `acme_account+key` is no longer created (I removed the previous file to check whether it's recreated) and so I'm unable to gather any logging from it **but** the function is never invoked. Either this is because my anonymous function is incorrect or because I've exceeded requests against the ACME endpoint. Removing the function and reverting to `m.GetCertificate` does not result in recreation of `acme_account+key` so I'm at a loss.

The `autocert` [`Manager`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert#Manager) type documents an [`*acme.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20211117183948-ae814b36b871/acme#Client) field which I'm not setting. The comment describes "if the Client.Key is nil, a new ECDSA P-256 key is generated" which is perhaps what I'm experiencing but it doesn't explain what I should do about it. Should I set this value to the content of `acme_account+key`?:

> *UPDATE* I tried decoding the private key, creating a `crypto.Signer` and passing this in `&acme.Client{Key: key}` but it made no evident difference

```
// Client is used to perform low-level operations, such as account registration
// and requesting new certificates.
//
// If Client is nil, a zero-value acme.Client is used with DefaultACMEDirectory
// as the directory endpoint.
// If the Client.Key is nil, a new ECDSA P-256 key is generated and,
// if Cache is not nil, stored in cache.
//
// Mutating the field after the first call of GetCertificate method will have no effect.
Client *acme.Client
```

Evidently, I'm using this incorrectly. I'm not receiving a cert from Let's Encrypt and so I'm unable to get a cert from the endpoint and unable to invoke the gRPC endpoint:

```sh
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect ${HOST}:${PORT}

grpcurl \
-proto health.proto \
${HOST}:${PORT} \
grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
Failed to dial target host "${HOST}:${PORT}": remote error: tls: internal error
```

Guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

‍♂️

Ugh :-(

I'd started using `SCRATCH` and hadn't copied the CA certificates

Once the container had CA certs, everything worked almost flawlessly.

I continue to have problems trying to use:

```golang
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
  ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
  GetCertificate: m.GetCertificate
}
```

And am using `m.TLSConfig()`

So, `autocert` works like a treat (though it's difficult to debug self-inflicted errors )